# Android Ripple effect duration in XML

Tags: android, android-drawable, rippledrawable

I have the following ripple xml defined:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_background_not_selected"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_foreground_selector"/>
</ripple>
```

When I apply this to a small view, it fine and looks reasonable... but when I apply this to a large view the ripple takes far too long!

How can I change the **duration/max radius/other values** of the ripple in the XML?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. This may help you

Comment: I've already visited there... that is not what I'm searching for, thanks.

Comment: You can't alter the duration. You can change the ripple bounds (and thus max radius) using `View.setHotspotBounds`, but I don't think that is going to help solve your problem.